# Application for a 462 working visa to Australia with an Irish passport

Tags: paperwork

I'm applying for a 462 working visa to Australia. I can't get past the 5th page for passport details, as it said my passport isn't eligible.

Answer (score 4):

Irish citizens are not eligible for [Subclass 462](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/work-holiday-462/first-work-holiday-462#Eligibility) Work and Holiday visas

> You must be a citizen of and hold a valid passport from one of these countries:

```
Argentina
Austria
Brazil
Chile
China, People's Republic of
Czech Republic
Ecuador
Greece
Hungary
Indonesia
Israel
Luxembourg
Malaysia
Mongolia
Papua New Guinea (PNG)
Peru
Poland
Portugal
San Marino
Singapore
Slovak Republic
Slovenia
Spain
Switzerland
Thailand
Türkiye
Uruguay
United States of America
Vietnam
```

---

Irish citizens must instead apply for a [Subclass 417](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/work-holiday-417/first-working-holiday-417#Eligibility) Working Holiday visa instead

> You must be a citizen of and hold a valid passport from one of these countries/jurisdictions:

```
Belgium
Canada
Republic of Cyprus
Denmark
Estonia
Finland
France
Germany
Hong Kong Special Administrative Region of the People's Republic of China
Republic of Ireland
Italy
Japan
Republic of Korea
Malta
Netherlands
Norway
Sweden
Taiwan (other than an official or diplomatic passport)
The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland (including British National Overseas passport holders)
```